# Как передать код ошибки через UART?

Tags: arduino, uart

Добрый день. 
имеется цифровая фото-видео камера с uart, jtag, usb. 
Создаю диагностируемое устройство в теории.
к диагностируемым параметрам можно отнести: 
- работоспособность батареи
- вспышка 
т.д.. 
Необходимо передать 8-битный код ошибки с камеры на Arduino. 
Выбрал изначально UART, c RX порта на камере передаю на TX порт на Arduino... 
но по ходу понял что т.к все передается побитово - коды ошибок могут смешаться.. 
Подскажите, есть ли выход из данной ситуации?

Comment: Что там с чем может смешаться?

Comment: код ошибки одного модуля(допустим вспышка) с кодом ошибки другого модуля(допустим батарея)

Comment: Вам нужен протокол высокого уровня, типа zmodem, с гарантией доставки.